# Jenkins shared library with inner class

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Im trying to use Jenkins shared library with inner classes. it failed when I try to create a new inner instance. import works so I guess its not something I configured wrong in Jenkins. Adding example..

**shared library:**

```
package src.org.jenkins
class global_func implements Serializable {
  static class global_A implements Serializable {
    def steps
    global_A(steps) {
        this.steps = steps
    }
     def A_func() {
         return true
     }
   }
}
```

**jenkins file:**

```
@Library('global_func')
import org.jenkins.global_func
global_utils = new global_func.global_A(steps)
```

**ERROR LOG:**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup     
failed:
WorkflowScript: 38: unable to resolve class global_func.global_A 
@ line 38, column 13.
A = new global_func.global_A(steps)
     ^

1 error 
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:129)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:123)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:517)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:480)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:253)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: can you please share error log ?

Comment: Can you show the tree structure of your library? It sounds like your library class is put in a wrong folder or something.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak global_func is under src/org/jenkins/ . the Jenkins file is in the root of the project. this works: A = new global_func()

Comment: It seems related to an exist issue of Jenkins groovy ClassLoader. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41896.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

1. The package is defined: `package src.org.jenkins`
2. Imports: `import org.jenkins.global_func`
3. Neither `global_func` nor `global_A` c'tors are defined, probably default c'tors are not good enough for you here.