# Jenkins shared library: Failure in instantiating class via Builder pattern

Tags: jenkins, builder, jenkins-groovy, cloudbees, jenkins-shared-libraries

CloudBees Core: 2.249.1.2-rolling

The code here is residing in a Jenkins shared library, which in turn is called by other Jenkins shared libraries.

Below is an implementation of a standard Builder pattern to create an instance of a custom HttpRequest class.

```
class HttpRequest {

    //Mandatory
    private final String url
    private final String httpMethod
    private final String requestContentType
    private final String acceptContentType

    //Optional
    private final String requestBody
    private final List<Integer> validResponseCodes

    private HttpRequest(HttpRequestBuilder httpRequestBuilder) {
        //Mandatory
        this.url = httpRequestBuilder.url
        this.httpMethod = httpRequestBuilder.httpMethod
        this.requestContentType = httpRequestBuilder.requestContentType
        this.acceptContentType = httpRequestBuilder.acceptContentType

        //Optional
        this.requestBody = httpRequestBuilder.requestBody
        this.validResponseCodes = httpRequestBuilder.validResponseCodes
    }

    static class HttpRequestBuilder {
        //Mandatory
        private final String url
        private final String httpMethod
        private final String requestContentType
        private final String acceptContentType

        //Optional
        private String requestBody
        private List<Integer> validResponseCodes

        HttpRequestBuilder(String url, String httpMethod, String requestContentType, String acceptContentType) {
            this.url = url
            this.httpMethod = httpMethod
            this.requestContentType = requestContentType
            this.acceptContentType = acceptContentType
        }

        HttpRequest build() {
            return new HttpRequest(this)
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param requestBody A string in a format valid according to the Content-Type.
         * @return
         */
        HttpRequestBuilder requestBody(String requestBody) {
            this.requestBody = requestBody
            return this
        }

        HttpRequestBuilder validResponseCodes(List<Integer> validResponseCodes) {
            this.validResponseCodes = validResponseCodes
            return this
        }
    }

    String getUrl() {
        return url
    }

    String getHttpMethod() {
        return httpMethod
    }

    String getRequestContentType() {
        return requestContentType
    }

    String getAcceptContentType() {
        return acceptContentType
    }

    String getRequestBody() {
        return requestBody
    }

    List<Integer> getValidResponseCodes() {
        return validResponseCodes
    }
}
```

The invocation in a class viz. Change.groovy is as follows:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest.HttpRequestBuilder(fullURL,
HttpConstants.HTTP_METHODS.PUT.name(),
HttpConstants.REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE_JSON,
HttpConstants.ACCEPT_TYPE_JSON
).requestBody(JsonOutput.toJson(authorizePayloadMap))
.validResponseCodes(validResponseCodes)
.build()
```

The error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
file:/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Cores%20Services/jobs/pseudo-id/branches/CORES-1961-retrieve-print-error/builds/5/libs/jenkins-shared-utilities/src/com/Change.groovy: 127: unable to resolve class HttpRequest.HttpRequestBuilder 
 @ line 127, column 35.
           HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest.HttpRequestBuilder(fullURL,
                                     ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.recompile(GroovyClassLoader.java:761)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:718)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell$TimingLoader.loadClass(CpsGroovyShell.java:170)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.global.UserDefinedGlobalVariable.getValue(UserDefinedGlobalVariable.java:57)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.getProperty(CpsScript.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:312)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyOwnerFirst(Closure.java:306)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:312)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyOwnerFirst(Closure.java:306)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:456)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at openSnapChange.call(openSnapChange.groovy:140)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.use(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:407)
    at openSnapChange.call(openSnapChange.groovy:59)
    at withStageNotification.call(withStageNotification.groovy:55)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor333.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: may I ask, why you are going through the trouble of implementing http requests yourself? There already is a jenkins plugin for this: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/

Comment: I already use the plugin, this is just the intermediate representation in the higher layers of code.

Comment: I'm very interested in this question. I had the same issue with a static inner class, also in a shared library, but I had no success in finding the solution. (Finally, I had to split both classes...) For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728417/jenkins-shared-library-with-inner-class